# How is md5Hash calculated for com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobInfo

Tags: google-app-engine, md5, blobstore, duplicates, message-digest

We're trying to avoid saving duplicate files. However, our md5 result is always different from  BlobInfo.

How we calculate it:

```
    MessageDigest messageDigest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    digest = messageDigest.digest(bytes);
    String digestString = DigestUtils.md5Hex(digest);
```

It doesn't match:with `(new BlobInfoFactory().loadBlobInfo(blobKey)).getMd5Hash();`

Example mismatches:

```
google vs my own calculation:
8cdeb6db94bc4fd156e2975fd8ebbcf2 vs 9003b37afbf3637de96c35774069453f 
65a25dafcba58d16d58a9c7585cc3932 vs 52383159f7d27417d50121aaee2728b5 
5cccc2d690fdc0c254234d5526876b34 vs 8196da9b6733daa60e08d927693df483
```

It is on production server. ( we didn't test dev environment )

Comment: Are you trying this in the devappserver or in prod?

Comment: Can you also post what you are getting and what you expect. Also, what kind of file are you uploading?

Comment: Both questions answered. The files are usually pdf and images (jpeg).

Comment: Two more questions, can you try with an empty file. How are you saving the files?

Comment: If we do empty files, this is the result "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" vs "59adb24ef3cdbe0297f05b395827453f".

Comment: The way we created file is similar to http://javatechnologytutorials.blogspot.com/p/google-app-engine-programatically.html createBlobFile(...). Except we do  writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)); instead of PrintWriter.

Comment: So, for the empty file GAE is computing the right MD5. It seems that there may be a problem with the way you are computing the md5hash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sebastian Kreft is right in the above discussion in comments.

The code I copied is wrong. it should just be:

```
String digestString = DigestUtils.md5Hex(bytes);
```

Sebastian Kreft used the trick to verify empty file's md5 which should always be d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e!